# IIS and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis

i'm trying to add asp.net feature on windows 7 i tried to turn it on using turn windows features on or off but it fails every time

so i download web platform installer and try it that way and it fails also

next i uninstall .net framework 4 restart again! and reinstall it and try again the previous steps but it fails the same

i need this installed so i can view it on iis7

anyone know what i can do with this to get it working i've searched and searched and everything fails

i get this error on the web platform installer 
Failed with 0x80070643 – Fatal Error during installation

please help i cant do my work with out it working :(

ok i did  a few things now get this error

> Server Error in '/pulse' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   type 'pulsesite.MvcApplication'.
>
> Source Error: 
>       Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb"
>   Inherits="pulsesite.MvcApplication"
>   Language="VB" %>
>
> Source File: /pulse/global.asax    Line: 1
>   Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>
> Version:4.0.30319.1

i know its ust about changing the code but i'm not good with c# anyone know how?

Comment: what are you trying to install with "web platform installer" that give you that error? What windows 7 do you have?

Comment: asp.net im trying to install as it would not work on windows features im using windows 7 64bit home premium

Comment: @sam - You can't install ASP.NET - you can install IIS or .NET framework. so which of those is it? Also, did you follow the exact steps described here? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731911.aspx

Comment: iis is installed by those steps the trouble is enabling asp.net in windows features

Comment: i followed these steps too

Comment: In the ApplicationHost.config file, delete the duplicate entry for the authorization rule. To do this, follow these steps:
Click Start, type Notepad in the Start Search box, right-click Notepad, and then click Run as administrator.

Note If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or click Continue.
On the File menu, click Open, type %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config in the File name box, and then click Open.
In the ApplicationHost.config file, delete the duplicate entry that

Comment: resembles the following code.
<add accessType="Allow" users="*" />but there is no duplicate or even anyline containing those words in the file

Comment: @sam your new error is 100% different issue please start new question.

Answer (score 1):

this might help somebody else... I just spent 10 minutes trying to figure out this same issue.

Check if your project is actually marked for Build in Configuration Manager. For some reason my MVC4 project was not checked.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna register asp.net with iis. So install iis using the features and then execute the command "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" with the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Comment: ok i did that and it says aspnet_regiis.exe -i is not recognised as and internal or external sommand operable program or batch file???

Comment: Try navigating to the folder "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" with the VS Command Prompt. It's located in that folder.

Comment: says the samething as before

Answer (score 0):

Check the System Event log for ASP.NET and related events. Then you can confidently search the web for information on the relevant errors you find.

Also, the path to the ASP.NET 4.0 IIS tool is:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Another method is to browse to the v4.0.30319 directory and find the file. If you can find it, hold down the shift key and right-click aspnet_regiis.exe. Choose copy as path, then paste into the command prompt with the -i flag. If it isn't in the directory, you have other problems. ;)